# How to fix firestore emulator connection

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the gcloud firestore emulator to test my local application. I'm using this liobrary to set up my spring connection with the database:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is my local config:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.emulator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.emulator.host-port=localhost:8082
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.emulator.project-id=local-project
```

I installed the emulator following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/emulator

The emulator starts normally with the command "gcloud emulators firestore start --host-port=localhost:8082" but when I use the repository to save somenting I got some errors:

```
myObjectRepository.save(myObjectLocal).block();

Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:537) ~[grpc-api-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:481) ~[grpc-stub-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]

        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.11.jar:3.5.11]
            at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1712) ~[reactor-core-3.5.11.jar:3.5.11]
    ...
    Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 1503010002
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:109) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
```

My code works and I can seve 'myObject' when I point to the remote/gcloud database.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the server is using TLS, but the client is not.

`1503010002` is a TLS record, similar to the [server hello](https://tls12.xargs.org/#server-hello/annotated).
However, in this case it's an alert record indicating an error:

- `15` in the beginning the record is not a handshake, but an alert (`SSL3_RT_ALERT`), which is a warning or fatal error.
- The following two bytes `0301` indicate the version of the TSL is 1.0: `TLS1_VERSION  x'0301'`.
- The rest of the record `0002` indicates the length of the alert data following the record is two bytes.

SSL record format info: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/2023?topic=sessions-ssl-record-format